# Изменить компилятор cc в линукс на другой

Tags: linux, c, gcc, clang

Хочу поменять компилятор по умолчанию с gcc на clang, но возник вопрос: не возникнет ли каких проблем в системе? Всмысле: при компиляции исходного кода усанавливаемых прог - какой компилятор используется? Точнее какая команда? `cc -...` || `gcc -...`?

Comment: как правило, при сборке подавляющего большинства программ, компилятор *c* можно (пере)определить переменной `CC`, а компилятор *c++* — переменной `CXX`. уточнить можно в исходниках конкретной программы.

Comment: связанный вопрос [How to use update-alternatives per user](https://serverfault.com/q/631447)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На сколько это безопасно зависит от того, что делашь с дистрибутивом: при обычном использовании в пакетного дистрибутива компилятор практически не используется (разве что для сборки ядерных модулей, но там ЕМНИП привязано к gcc), и соответственно это не должно приносить проблем. Если собираешь пакеты в дистрибутиве, то по-умолчанию в дебе разброд и шатание: разные пакеты использует и gcc, и сс, и /usr/bin/cc. Но если указывать переменные СС/CXX, то всё должно быть в порядке. Ядро само по-умолчанию собирается gcc.

В генту проблем от переключения симлинков /usr/bin/{cc,c++} быть не должно т.к. системно используется компилятор заданный в make.conf. Использование clang'а, как системного сопряжено с рядом трудностей, но это уже отдельная тема.

Про rpm-based дистры сказать ничего не могу.

Итого имеем: переключить можно, но польза от этого минимальна, и ни кто не сможет гарантировати, что рано или поздно какой-то плохонаписанного скрипта сборки не даст граблями по голове.

Я бы не стал менять системные ссылки. Проще всего и безопасней ИМХО сделать симлинки для своего пользователя (с точностью до путей):

```
mkdir -p ~/bin
ln -s /usr/bin/clang     ~/bin/cc
ln -s /usr/bin/clang++   ~/bin/c++
ln -s /usr/bin/clang-cpp ~/bin/cpp
```

И установить соответствующий PATH:

```
echo 'export PATH="~/bin:$PATH"' >>~/.profile'
```

Comment: Вопрос был не о том, как это сделать, а о том: не будет ли проблем в системе от такой замены?

Comment: Дополнил малость более развёрнуто